# Bulk Replace/Rename of the "Title" Meta Tag in HTML Files

Tags: windows, metadata, metadata-editor

I am trying to replace/insert unique  meta tags in/into numerous HTML files. The new  meta tag information is stored in a CSV file. I tried using Exiftool but it does not support W for HTML files. Does anyone know any other script/app similar to Exiftool that would allow me to complete this task automatically, instead of manually opening every single file and copy/pasting new meta data into them?

I have Windows.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the new information is stored in a .csv file I am guessing that there is some sort of rule or mapping between either the original and new metadata or the filenames and the new metadata.

**Before doing any bulk file operations make sure that all of the existing files are either in an up to date version control system, are backed up to another device or safely zipped!**

**Personally** I would use [python](https://www.python.org/), (freely available for Windows and many/most other platforms), and it's [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) or [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) *(regular expression)* library tools as this will allow for rule based replacement.

Otherwise many text editors such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) (also free) allow search and replace in files **but** this is better suited to when there is a simple rule such as replace all meta fred tags with ....
[image: Notepad++ find & replace in files]

Comment: Thank you, @SteveBarnes. Essentially, I am trying to bulk replace title meta tag in numerous HTML files (each name is *unique* to the file). I have a CSV file with two columns: (1) file name; (2) new title meta tag. So I am looking for an app that can take those meta tags and import them into the *respective* file names, i.e. a function similar to bulk replace functionalities in ExifTool for images, and Bulk Rename Utility for file names.